# Error while installing screenkey?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, package, archlinux

I tried to install screenkey application but I had an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/screenkey", line 23, in <module>
    from Screenkey import APP_NAME, APP_DESC, VERSION
ImportError: No module named Screenkey
```

python version is 2.7 and the package of screen is 0.2.

Comment: Screenkey (the application to show your keypresses on your screen) has nothing to do with screen (the terminal multiplexer). What does "package of screen is 0.2" mean? How did you try to install Screenkey?

Comment: I downloaded the package from the launchpad and then `sudo dpkg -i package` after that I runned the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally installed **screenkey** from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/screenkey) and I didn't have any problem.

It's actually not the original version and not the same as the launchpad version but it's pretty good.

As said in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/screenkey) package description it's a

> Screencast tool to show your keys inspired by Screenflick, based on key-mon. Active fork with new features.

I Hope this can help You.